# "The non-generic method 'xxx' cannot be used with type arguments" error when using a web service

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-services, generics, asmx

I have the following in a C# web service:

```
namespace ProductPieceManagement_WS {
    public enum ProductType {
        Unknown = -1,
        SellItem = 0,
        RentalItem = 2
    }

    [WebServiceBinding(ConformsTo = WsiProfiles.BasicProfile1_1)]
    [System.ComponentModel.ToolboxItem(false)]
    public class ProductPieceManagement : WebService {
        [WebMethod]
        public string GetProductTypeEnumIDs() {
            return GetEnumIDs<ProductType>();
        }

        [WebMethod]
        public string GetEnumIDs<T>() {
            /* Returns a comma-delimited list of values from the specified Enum "T". */
            ...some code...
        }
    }
}
```

and, in my ASP.Net page:

```
ProductPieceManagement ppm = new ProductPieceManagement();

string myVar = ppm.GetProductTypeEnumIDs();
```

this all works fine.  But, if I change it to:

```
ProductPieceManagement ppm = new ProductPieceManagement();

string myVar = ppm.GetEnumIDs<ProductType>();
```

I receive the following error:

> The non-generic method
>   'ProductPieceManagement_WS.ProductPieceManagment.GetEnumIDs()' cannot
>   be used with type arguments

The idea is to get rid of "GetProductTypeEnumIDs", because I have to do similar things with different enums throughout the site.  I don't want to have to create a separate method for each one.

Can anyone please help me get rid of the error, and keep the generic function?  Or, is that not an option in a web service?

Comment: If you are starting on new development, then you have chosen the wrong web services platform. ASMX is a legacy technology, and should not be used for new development. WCF or ASP.NET Web API should be used for all new development of web service clients and servers. One hint: Microsoft has retired the [ASMX Forum](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/asmxandxml/threads) on MSDN.

Comment: ASMX has no support for generics at all, and in fact generics don't make sense. SOAP web services are meant to be cross-platform. The WSDL file describing the service has no way to describe a generic operation.

Comment: Thanks John.  Unfortunately, I've inherited this one.  I will keep your comments in mind for future work.